# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I try to implement bigquery in python 2.7 on jupyter notebook. I think my code is correct, but i'm getting the error "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'query'"

```
# Create SQL query using natality data after the year 2000
query = """
SELECT
  weight_pounds,
  is_male,
  mother_age,
  plurality,
  gestation_weeks,
  ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(CONCAT(CAST(YEAR AS STRING), CAST(month AS STRING)))) AS hashmonth
FROM
  publicdata.samples.natality
WHERE year > 2000
"""

# Call BigQuery and examine in dataframe
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
df = client.query(query + " LIMIT 100").to_dataframe()
df.head()
```

The error message i got is:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-caf57b3f137d> in <module>()
      2 from google.cloud import bigquery
      3 client = bigquery.Client()
----> 4 df = client.query(query + " LIMIT 100").to_dataframe()
      5 df.head()

AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Comment: Try `print dir(client)` and see what it shows.

Comment: Are you running in virtualenv? If not, install virtualenv and the requirements inside virtualenv then run your script.

Comment: I'm running in jupyter notebook on Google Cloud Platform AI notebook...

Answer (score 3):

Problem fixed! Just need to update the bigquery via
`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`